# adding svg image to splash screen flutter

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

I want to show a svg image in splash screen.
I tried flutter_native_splash package but it's only work with jpg & png. Is there any alternative way to add svg image to splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it manually for Android and iOS like described in the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen).

For Android you can use a tool like [Respresso](https://respresso.io/image-converter/) to convert your SVG to an Android vector drawable.

Xcode 12 and higher also supports SVG in storyboards as far as I know.